# How to find notification's alert type in Android NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationlistenerservice

I am currently building an Android application that tracks all notifications in a phone and categorize them by their alert type (silenced, vibrated, ring bell).

I've implemented `NotificationListenerService`.

How can I access the alert type in `onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification)` function?